# How to create external download link in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How to create link with preventDefault and on click it must run download file from external url in React

```
return (
<Link to="/page">
 <img src={src} />
 <a href="https://external_photo_uri/pic.jpg" download />
</Link>
)
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you have it wrapped in a `<Link` element?

Comment: Because I have a route if I click on image

Comment: You can't do both, you either have an `a` or a `Link` however you can always listen for the click of one or the other and trigger the 2nd action. I don't know the exact details for the react router. If by any chance you are using the [`connected-react-router`](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router) you can dispatch the `push` action to trigger a transition after a user has clicked on the `a` but then not prevent the default action of the `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. I create parent div on anchor tag and onClick run e.stopPropagation()

Answer (score 3):

You can create a normal anchor tag with download attribute.

Example

```
<a href="myurl" download> <img src={src} /></a>
```

Comment: How can I prevent event bubling?

Comment: No need to prevent event bubbling in this case, you can try and check.

Comment: Your advice does not work. I have Link at background and It fires Link, not "a" tag

Comment: Dont add the anchor tag inside link, move it outside. If you want to use router Link then u can use

<Link to="https://external_photo_uri/pic.jpg" download target="_self"></Link>

Comment: but I need download button on my image

Comment: Update my answer

Comment: I need link inside image, not image inside link

Comment: What’s the difference??

Comment: If I click on image, I have to navigate to photo description route via react-router, but when I click on download button, I  need to download photo via external link

Comment: the image instead of downloading opens in a new tab. how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **react-download-link**

A simple component to download data from a client-side cache (e.g. flux, redux). Design to be used with browserify or webpack.

Install with:

```
npm install --save react-download-link
```

Include with:

```
import DownloadLink from "react-download-link";
```

Use:

```
<DownloadLink
    filename="myfile.txt"
    exportFile={() => "My cached data"}                                           
>
    Save to disk                                                
</DownloadLink>
```

Or with Promises:

```
<DownloadLink
filename="myfile.txt"
exportFile={() => Promise.resolve("My cached data")}>
    Save to disk                                                
 </DownloadLink>
```

The component will default to an anchor tag, but the tagName prop will accept a string of any other HTML tag you prefer, such as 'button'.

Comment: Can you explain how it use with external download URL ??

Comment: @AlanWake simplly use axios to return the promise () => axios.get('external link');

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click on the w3schools logo to download the image:<p>

<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
  <img src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>

<p><b>Note:</b> The download attribute is not supported in Edge version 12, IE, Safari 10 (and earlier), or Opera version 12 (and earlier).</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_download.asp

Comment: I use React library, not plain html